# Using two full stops in java between methods, variables, or objects

Tags: java, object, methods

I'm sure there are explanations on the internet of basic feature of java as I would imagine, but because I'm completely clueless on what this action is trying to achieve I'm not describing the search properly and no results are coming up that explain what I'm confused with. So please guide me in the right direction as I can't find the way to search for what this means.

So below I have an example of what I'm confused with, from the line `GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();`. I know how to use methods with an object (e.g. object.method()) and such or with a variable, but this quoted line is different with two full stops and methods and not one. What is it trying to do exactly? It seems to be creating a "gl" object to me, and then its using a getGL2() method but but *also* a getGL(), and when I try test using the same form with some methods I've made I can't chain them at the same time like that. So I would use a variable or object and do ".method().method2()" and it won't work.

Also I don't understand how its creating an object "`GL2 gl`" with `GL2` being the type and `gl` being the name of the object but after the "=" there is no "new" like I usually see.

Code example:

```
  public void init (GLAutoDrawable drawable) { 
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    //GL2 gl2 = drawable.getGL().getGL2(); 
    gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1); // black
    //gl2.glClearColor(0,0,0,1); 
  }
```

Comment: Check [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jogamp.jogl/jogl-all/2.0.2/javax/media/opengl/GLAutoDrawable.java) is out.

Comment: `getGL()` is called on the `drawable` which returns an object on which `getGL2()` is called and this method returns a reference to a `GL2` object

Answer (score 3):

First, the method `init` takes an argument `drawable`.

`drawable` is of the type `GLAutoDrawable`, which has a method called `getGL()`.

For example, the class `GLAutoDrawable` could be something like this:

```
public class GLAutoDrawable {

  // other stuff

  public GL getGL(){
    // other stuff
    return gl;
  }

  // other stuff

}
```

Here, `getGL()` returns a variable called `gl`, which is of the type `GL`. Although this isn't specified in the code you provided, I'll just assume it's called `GL`.

(For more information on return statements, read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Then, the variable that is returned from `getGL()` has the method `getGL2()` called.

For example, the class `GL` could look something like this:

```
public class GL {

  // other stuff

  public GL2 getGL2(){
    // other stuff
    return gl2;
  }

  // other stuff

}
```

The method `getGL2()` in the class `GL` returns an object called `gl2`, which is what the final variable in your code is.

**Basically, `GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();` is the same thing as:**

```
GL g = drawable.getGL();
GL2 gl = g.getGL2();
```

**except it saves space without having to name a new variable.**

Comment: Thank you this is a lot more clear now. I'm going to try this with some random classes I try to see how it works in practice. If I get confused again i might ask for more clarification with a new example.

Answer (score 2):

`GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();`

`drawable` has a `getGL()` method with returns an object (assume it's a `GL`). The `GL` object has a `getGL2()` method, so you are just calling `getGL2()` on the result of `getGL()`.

This can make code easier to read, but if any of your "chain" returns null you will be in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a method on an object consists of four parts: object reference, name of method, parameters, return value.

```
varToStoreReturnValue = objectReference.methodName(parameters);
```

Since a method can return an object, you can call a method to retrieve an object reference on which to call another method:

```
objectReference1 = objectReference.methodName(parameters);
varToStoreReturnValue = objectReference2.anotherMethodName(newParameters);
```

This example above could be written as:

```
varToStoreReturnValue = objectReference.methodName(parameters).anotherMethodName(newParameters);
```

If no parameters are required, this would look like:

```
ReturnType varToStoreReturnValue = objectReference.methodName().anotherMethodName();
```

... which in your case would look like:

```
GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. `returnValue = objectReference2.anotherMethodName(newParameters);` Im not sure how this normally appears though, what is "returnValue"? I thought return values are only after a method that is expecting a return value of a certain type. If you are putting = after a return value how are you returning it without typing "return" in front of it?